# How to create a drop down list by performing a query with the option selected in previous dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a form with network drop down list

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="form-field-1">Network</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="a_network"  name="a_network" onchange="getplan();">
                <option>Choose Network</option>
                    <?php 
                        $q=mysql_query("select * from network");
                        while($rq=mysql_fetch_array($q))
                        {
                    ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rq['id'];?>"><?php echo $rq['network_name'];?></option>
                    <?php
                        } 
                    ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have another drop down list called plan for which the options are fetched from a database depending on the network option selected

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="form-field-1">Plan</label>
    <div class="controls">
            <select id="plan"  name="plan">
                <option>Choose Plan</option>
                    <?php 
                        $q=mysql_query("select * from sim_plans where network_id='$nid'");
                        while($rq=mysql_fetch_array($q))
                        {
                    ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rq['plan_id'];?>"><?php echo $rq['plan'];?></option>
                    <?php
                        } 
                    ?>
            </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here $nid should be the value of network option selected. How to do this. I thought may be we can use onchange function with network but can't figure out how.

```
<script>
function getplan()
{
var netid = $("#a_network").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo site_url('sim_orders/get_plan')?>/"+netid,
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data)
        {
            var len=data.length;
            $('#plan').empty();
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                var id=data[i]['id'];
                var name=data[i]['name'];
                $('#plan').append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
            }
        },
        error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("Error in getting plans");
        }
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
public function get_plan($id)
{
    $plans=array();
    $q=mysql_query("select * from sim_plans where network_id='$id'");
    while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        $plans[]=array("id"=>$res['plan_id'],"name"=>$res['plan']);
    }

    echo json_encode($plans);
}
```

Not showing any options after choosing the network
Hi! Got it. I forgot to put a comma after success function. So didn't get the drop down. Thanks for help!

Comment: Use jquery `ajax` to achieve this

Comment: First of all the syntax you're using is deprecated.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Can you brief on how to use ajax to achieve this

Comment: Are you familiar with `jquery` ?

Comment: Yes, a little bit @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Check this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I have used ajax before to post and get data from controller in codeigniter framework. But I don't get how I can use it here @MayankPandeyz

Comment: On the change of first dropdown make an ajax call and get the data for the selected value and put it in second dropdown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151273/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-sruthi-sripathi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="form-field-1">Network</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="a_network"  name="a_network" onchange="getplan();">
                    <option>Choose Network</option>
                        <?php 
                            $q=mysql_query("select * from network");
                            while($rq=mysql_fetch_array($q))
                            {
                        ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $rq['id'];?>"><?php echo $rq['network_name'];?></option>
                        <?php
                            } 
                        ?>
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="form-field-1">Plan</label>
        <div class="controls">
                <select id="plan"  name="plan"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function getplan()
    {
    var network_id = $("#a_network").val();
    $("#plan").empty();

            if(network_id != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "getPlanbyNetworkID.php",
                    data: {network_id: network_id},
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#plan").append(data);
                });
            }
    }
    </script>
```

Now create the page named getPlanbyNetworkID.php and write the required query there:

```
<?php 
        $network_id = $_POST['network_id'];

        $q=mysql_query("select * from sim_plans where network_id='$network_id'");
    $dropdown = '<option>Choose Plan...</option>';
        while($rq=mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {
    $dropdown .=  '<option value="' . $rq['plan_id'] . '">' . $rq['plan'] . '</option>';
        }
echo $dropdown;
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I added the code as suggested. See the post. But still not getting plan options